# R- Count of Specific values and Print in R

Tags: r, frequency-analysis

I have created data frame "df"

```
Age Sex Income
45  Female  3000
25  Female  5000
34  Male    4500
```

Now I want to count no of females in sex column and Print it like " No of Females = 2" without using any special package

I could see number of male and female while giving code: `summary(df$Sex)`or `table(df$sex)`

Tried doing `Femdata=df[which(df$Sex =='Female'),]` not working
`sum(df$sex=="Female", na.rm=TRUE)` not working
`df$sex[df$sex=="Female"]` not working
`length(df[df$sex=="Female"])` not working
Kindly let me know the solution And also Kindly help me in Printing with some statement and then answer

Comment: the data frame is in a table form but in question is appearing as one line

Comment: Why did `sum(df$sex=="Female", na.rm=TRUE)` not work? What output did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can use `cat` to print extra information with an answer:

```
> cat("No of Females = ", nrow(mydf[mydf$Sex == "Female", ]))
No of Females =  2
```

---

If you want the result as a character string to use elsewhere, it's probably easier to use `sprintf` or `paste`:

```
> sprintf("No of Females = %s", nrow(mydf[mydf$Sex == "Female", ]))
[1] "No of Females = 2"
```

Comment: Thanks your Print statement is working fine but I am getting result "No of females = 0 ". Don't know why so giving my below code. So its a function named censusSummary where path is given by dataFile. This census-income.data does not have column name , so scanning other census-income.features.txt data to read the name and assign as the column name of census-income.data file

Comment: censusSummary <- function(dataFile) 
{
df <- data.frame(read.table(dataFile, header=FALSE, sep=","))
features = scan("/Users/computer1/Downloads/Big Data/census-income.features.txt",sep = "\n",what = character())
colnames(df) = features

}
censusSummary("/Users/computer1/Downloads/Big Data/census-income.data")

Comment: df <- data.frame(read.table("/Users/computer1/Downloads/Big Data/census-income.data", header=FALSE, sep=","))
> names(df)
 [1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" "V16" "V17" "V18" "V19"
[20] "V20" "V21" "V22" "V23" "V24" "V25" "V26" "V27" "V28" "V29" "V30" "V31" "V32" "V33" "V34" "V35" "V36" "V37" "V38"
[39] "V39" "V40" "V41" "V42"
> cat("No of Females = ", nrow(df[df$V13 == "Female", ]))
No of Females =  0

Comment: > table(df$V13)

 Female    Male 
 103984   95539

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, to get the count:

```
sum(df$Sex == 'Female')
```

and to print it, your options are as Ananda Mahto said.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is specifically about printing. This option was already in their question.

Comment: Undid my downvote. Saw your comment,  but still don't feel this answers the question.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: no, it was about both counting and printing - and the OP was almost surely incorrect in claiming this doesn't work for counting, so the thing we need to find out is: why?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
nrow(df[df[,2]=="Female",])
```

The issue here is you missed a comma (,) in matrix dataframe, so it returns error.
Also the column names are case sensitive, it must be an exact match!